# Where can I find the tmp directory where application logs are written on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Craft CMS application deployed on Google App Engine Standard.

I need to view the logs written from the application to debug a 503 error which I suspect is due to a failed database connection.

Google App Engine cannot write files to the application and gives instructions to write everything to `/tmp`

I found one of their tutorials saying to use:

```
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

So I'm writing there. On the dashboard, the logs only give the HTTP code, but I need the actual error written from craft which is usually in `storage/logs/web.log`

How can I find `/tmp` on GAE via their console?

Answer (score 1):

App engine Standard is containerized in a way that you don't actually have access to the infrastructure running the application and it's files, as it is fully manged.

The logs that your application generates are visible from [Stackdriver Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), on Stackdriver there are some logs that are nos visible by default, however under the logname you can select all logs.

Also if you want to set a special output for the logs only some outputs are available on the selector therefor the standard output is the recommended to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your logs to the standard output rather than a file. That way, stackdriver will be able to pick them up which you will be able to query later in GCP.